# c# Parallel.Invoke (zero speed improvements)

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

Below is my little bit refactored (+ some extra code because of out-parameters) simple method where I tried to make things faster with Parallel.Invoke(...).

(please ignore **async** word inside variables :)).

Synchronous version is the same - with synchronous calls to the same 7 methods.

All of the 7 methods are quite simple - they are just populating and returning collection.

Now - what I find amazing is this: **both** methods executes in almost **identical** time (~ 6 seconds).

How is this possible *or* am I missing something ?

```
private static void GenerateCachingHelpersAsync(
     SingleVODCache _svc,
     Dictionary<int, DataRow> _dicFirstContentsFilter,
     DataSet _ds,
     out ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataRow> _cdicValidContentCatalogPrices,
     out ConcurrentDictionary<int, DataRow> _cdicAllMetaDataHelper,
     out List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> _helperContentMetaDataSync,
     out ConcurrentDictionary<int, DataRow> _cdicAllAssetsHelper,
     out List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> _helperContentAssetsSync,
     out Dictionary<int, OneContentAllViewsHelper> _dicAllContentsViewsHelper,
     out ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<Category>> _cdicValidContentCategories
     )
  {
     ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataRow> _cdicValidContentCatalogPricesAsync = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataRow>();
     ConcurrentDictionary<int, DataRow> _cdicAllMetaDataHelperAsync = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, DataRow>();
     List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> _helperContentMetaDataSyncAsync = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
     ConcurrentDictionary<int, DataRow> _cdicAllAssetsHelperAsync = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, DataRow>();
     List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> _helperContentAssetsSyncAsync = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();
     Dictionary<int, OneContentAllViewsHelper> _dicAllContentsViewsHelperAsync = new Dictionary<int, OneContentAllViewsHelper>();
     ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<Category>> _cdicValidContentCategoriesAsync = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, List<Category>>();

     Parallel.Invoke(
        () =>
        {
           _cdicValidContentCatalogPricesAsync = BuildValidContentCatalogPricesHelper(_ds.Tables[GetCMSDataTableIndex(m_eCMSDataTablesIndexes.CONTENT_CATALOG_PRICE_SYNC)]);
        },
        () =>
        {
           _cdicAllMetaDataHelperAsync = BuildAllMetaDataHelper(_ds.Tables[GetCMSDataTableIndex(m_eCMSDataTablesIndexes.META_DATA)]);
        },
        () =>
        {
           _helperContentMetaDataSyncAsync = BuildContentMetaDataSyncHelper(_ds.Tables[GetCMSDataTableIndex(m_eCMSDataTablesIndexes.CONTENT_META_DATA_SYNC)]);
        },
        () =>
        {
           _cdicAllAssetsHelperAsync = BuildAllAssetsHelper(_ds.Tables[GetCMSDataTableIndex(m_eCMSDataTablesIndexes.ASSETS)]);
        },
        () =>
        {
           _helperContentAssetsSyncAsync = BuildContentAssetsSyncHelper(_ds.Tables[GetCMSDataTableIndex(m_eCMSDataTablesIndexes.CONTENT_ASSET_SYNC)]);
        },
        () =>
        {
           _dicAllContentsViewsHelperAsync = BuildAllContensViewsVotesHelper(_ds.Tables[GetCMSDataTableIndex(m_eCMSDataTablesIndexes.CONTENT_VIEWS)], _dicFirstContentsFilter, _svc.MetaData.HowManyPastDaysForMostViewed);
        },
        () =>
        {
           _cdicValidContentCategoriesAsync = BuildValidContentCategoriesHelper(_ds.Tables[GetCMSDataTableIndex(m_eCMSDataTablesIndexes.CONTENT_CATEGORY_SYNC)], _dicFirstContentsFilter, _svc.AllCategories);
        }
        );

     _cdicValidContentCatalogPrices = _cdicValidContentCatalogPricesAsync;
     _cdicAllMetaDataHelper = _cdicAllMetaDataHelperAsync;
     _helperContentMetaDataSync = _helperContentMetaDataSyncAsync;
     _cdicAllAssetsHelper = _cdicAllAssetsHelperAsync;
     _helperContentAssetsSync = _helperContentAssetsSyncAsync;
     _dicAllContentsViewsHelper = _dicAllContentsViewsHelperAsync;
     _cdicValidContentCategories = _cdicValidContentCategoriesAsync;
  }
```

Comment: Are your calculations CPU-bound. I/O-bound or memory-bound?

Comment: CPU/Memory bound. No I/O operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Parallel.Invoke` method will *[possibly run the code asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* depending on whether the code will run faster synchronously or not.  In your case, if you're just populating collections and there is no expensive I/O or service calls, it's probably just running everything synchonously.

What you should do is group the low-cost construction into one block of code and then separate the more expensive calls (i.e. DB or web service) into separate blocks, since these are likely what would add more wait time.

EDIT: Additional quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

*No guarantees are made about the order in which the operations execute or whether they execute in parallel.*